# Is Tobias Whale vegan?

Tags: dc, black-lightning-2018

TV Tropes [claims](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilVegetarian) that Tobias Whale is vegan:

> In Black Lightning, ruthless crime boss Tobias Whale claims to adhere
>   to a vegan diet.

But he seems to be having caviar when he meets with Khalil:

> TOBIAS: Like it or not, every successful person remembers two things in life.
>   The first time they try caviar, and the first time they can enjoy it without worrying what it cost.
>
> <sub>*Black Lightning*, "The Book of Blood: Chapter One: Requiem"</sub>

And when he meets with encryption specialist Todd, he does provide some Toficken for him, but seems contemptuous of him being vegan.

Does Tobias maintain a vegan or vegetarian diet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I think TV Tropes may be misstating Tobias Whale's dietary preference. He uses veganism as part of his lie about the source of his longevity (actually due to a serum):

> Henderson: How is it you never seem to age?
>   Tobias: Well, a vegan lifestyle with a little yoga really does work. I keep saying black folks gotta get off of that fried chicken & watermelon, Kool-aid diet. Plus I do my best to stay out of the sun.

And he accommodates [Todd Green](https://blacklightning.fandom.com/wiki/Todd_Green)'s veganism, but also mocks Todd in *Black Lightning* Season 2, Episode 10: "The Book of Rebellion: Chapter Three: Angelitos Negros":

> "One of these new transformed vegan Negroes"

Lastly, as Jack notes, [a scene from an episode near the end of Season 1](https://images.app.goo.gl/ryv6GiS7sqKZqBEh8) shows what appears to be a steak on the plater of what he's eating.

[image: Tobias noshing on a rare steak]

Comment: OK, so he's just making something up to insult Henderson, seemingly.

Comment: Yup. I modified the TV Tropes entry to indicate that his claim is dubious in the light of the rest of the series.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an episode towards the end of season 1 which shows him eating a big rare steak: https://images.app.goo.gl/ryv6GiS7sqKZqBEh8